# LeetCode pivot++ vs pivot+1

Tags: java, binary-search

I was doing the binary search question on LeetCode. The autograder says "Time Limit Exceeded" when I use pivot++ or pivot--, but it accepts the solution if I use pivot+1 or pivot-1. Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

p.s The question states my solution must have O(log n) time complexity.

This code is not accepted:

```java
class Solution {

    public int search(int[] nums, int target) {
        
        int left = 0;
        int right = nums.length - 1;
        int pivot = 0;
        
        while (left <= right) {
            pivot = left+(right-left)/2;
            if (nums[pivot] == target) return pivot;
            if (nums[pivot] > target) right = pivot--;
            else left = pivot++;
        }
        return -1; 
    }
}
```

This code is accepted:

```java
class Solution {
    public int search(int[] nums, int target) {
        
        int left = 0;
        int right = nums.length - 1;
        int pivot = 0;
        
        while (left <= right) {
            pivot = left+(right-left)/2;
            if (nums[pivot] == target) return pivot;
            if (nums[pivot] > target) right = pivot-1;
            else left = pivot+1;
        }
        return -1;   
    }
}
```

Comment: Both return the value of `pivot` incremented by 1. But `pivot++` **modifies `pivot`** and `pivot+1` will **not change** `pivot`. That's a significant change in what your code does.

Answer (score 2):

Also, pivot++ will first return the value of pivot and then increment it, pivot+1 will return the incremented value, if you use ++pivot it will first increment the value of pivot and then return the new incremented value

Answer (score 1):

```java
int x = 5;

int y = x++; //assigns x to y and then increments x, so y = 5, x = 6;

int z = ++x; //increments x and then assigns its value to y, so y = 7, z = 7;

int e = z + 1; //adds 1 to z and assigns result to e, but doesn't change z, so e = 8, z = 7.
```